# Installing pg -v 0.17.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg, bundle-install

I'm using/I want to use Postgresql as database, but when I type "bundle install" or "bundle update", I get this error, what do I do to fix this? :)

```
    Installing pg (0.17.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rsvmrk/.bundler/tmp/22196/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/rsvmrk/.bundler/tmp/22196/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed PostgreSQL 8.4.x or later (with headers, -dev packages, etc) as suggested there: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing pre-requisite libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-devel
```

Then install pg

```
gem install pg
```

Comment: I've tried using that command, but the terminal says: "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: apt-get is not installed on your system, I hope wget is installed on your system. run "wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu4_amd64.deb" then "sudo dpkg -i apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu4_amd64.deb"

Comment: expecting you have 64bit system.

Comment: Hm... Nothing really happens. Still "command not found". Is there a special place where I'm suppose to install these commands?

Comment: check it out http://askubuntu.com/questions/295171/how-to-install-apt-get-package-manager

Comment: You keep assuming that OP is using Ubuntu, but they clearly aren't if they don't have apt-get installed.

Answer (score 5):

For those on OS X, I recommend using home-brew to install:

```
brew install postgresql
```

More info [at Homebrew's site](http://brew.sh), if you're not already a user, including how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

in order to communicate with a PostgreSQL database backend you need the  **libpq-dev** package.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

then continue the package installation

```
gem install pg
```