# Need Help Getting Past Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I am going through this Rails tutorial and they are having me install and app of theirs. In doing so I ran into this error message. This message came after I ran rails `new _4.2.2_ new toy_app` and subsequently running `bundle install`. I also tried running the `sudo gem install pg -v0.17.1` command to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Installing pg 0.17.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/alopex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150710-6312-1vbswpn.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/alopex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/alopex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alopex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

```
    alopex@alopex-TH55-HD:~/work-space$ sudo gem install pg -v 0.17.1
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: **NEVERMIND!**

This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25227977/5004918

Comment: Maybe [think link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem) will help.